# why after i destroy all the records in the model every time i reload the "index page" it will load five new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I destroy all the record using `@cart.destroy`  one by one. But when i refresh `/carts`,there will be 5 new carts every time.
index.html.erb:

```
<% @carts.each do |cart| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', cart %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cart_path(cart) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
....
```

the rails severs information:

```
Processing by CartsController#index as HTML
Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts"
Rendered carts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 24.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

carts_controller.rb:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

 def index
  @carts = Cart.all
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
  @cart = Cart.new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def create
  @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.save
    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cart }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.update(cart_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @cart.destroy
 session[:cart_id]=nil
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to store_index_url ,notice: 'Your cart is currently empty'}
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private

def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

def cart_params
  params[:cart]
end

 def invalid_cart
  logger.error "Attemp to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
  redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'

 end
end
```

When i use rails console and `Cart.destroy_all`. It can work. There is no more cart show at the index. But why `@cart.destroy` doesn't work?

how to correct it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> @cart.destroy

will remove only current record

if you want to remove all records from Cart model use

> `Cart.destroy_all`

to remove all records from Cart Model

Answer (score 0):

@cart.destroy will only destroy a single record. To destroy every cart record in your database, you'd have to do something like:

```
Cart.all { |f| f.destroy }
```

Post your entire carts controller - there isn't enough here to figure out why new items are being created.

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement maybe could not work at all, at least in my test environment. Maybe it is Rails or Ruby version issue.

You can do things like that

```
def destroy
   ....................
   Cart.destroy(@cart.map {|i| i.id})
   .............................
end
```

Then all records corresponding to @cart will be deleted. But I think if you assign value to "@cart" in method "index" here, @cart in method "destroy" can't keep the value.

If you are very sure you want destroy all the records in method "destroy" no matter what, you could

```
def destroy
   Cart.destroy_all
   .............................
end
```

Comment: After i change the destroy method, an error `undefined method 'map' for #<Cart:0x007f12c148a90>` occurs

Comment: You'd better check the @carts, I think you assign value in method "index", but it didn't keep the value until you call "destroy". In "destroy", "@carts" might be a uninitialized variable. For simple, just "Cart.destroy_all".